# php variable assignment confusion

Tags: php

While reading a book about php I cam across a piece of code that logically doesn't make sense to me. The line of code is part of a class function:

```
private function replaceTags( $pp = false ) {
    //get the tags in the page
    if( $pp == false ) {
        $tags = $this->page->getTags();
    } else {
        $tags = $this->page->getPPTags();
    }
    //go through them all
    foreach( $tags as $tag => $data ) {
        //if the tag is an array, then we need to do more than a simple find and replace!
        if( is_array( $data ) ) {
            if( $data[0] == 'SQL' ) {
                //it is a cached query...replace tags from the database
                $this->replaceDBTags( $tag, $data[1] );
            } elseif( $data[0] == 'DATA' ) {
                //it is some cahched data...replace tags from cached data
                $this->replaceTags( $tag, $data[1] );
            }
        } else {
            //replace the content
            $newContent = str_replace( '{' . $tag . '}', $data, $this->page->setContent( $newContent ) );
            $this->page->setContent( $newContent );
        }
    }
}
```

The specific line that doesn't make sense to me is:

```
$newContent = str_replace( '{' . $tag . '}', $data, $this->page->setContent( $newContent ) );
```

How can you pass the variable "$newContent" to "setContent( $newContent )" when it doesn't have a value yet?

Any explanations?

Comment: Where is the content being generated?

Answer (score 0):

That statement is executing in a for loop so, `$newContent` will **hold the value in another loop** to use.

In the first execution, `$newContent` will be empty but on the next iteration it will have a value to replace.

```
foreach( $tags as $tag => $data ) {
    if ....
    } else {
        //replace the content
        $newContent = str_replace( '{' . $tag . '}', $data, $this->page->setContent( $newContent ) );
     // ^
     // Now next time when the loop executes again it will have a 
     // $newContent to process.

        $this->page->setContent( $newContent );
    }
}
```

Comment: You see that is where I get confused, because actually the method setContent is nothing more than a setter and doesn't return anything.

Comment: @robertrocha, `$this -> page -> setContent()` is probably returning something. Even with a empty string. Do `var_dump($this -> page -> setContent($newContent));` to see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think this variable "$newContent" doesn't have a value?
Actually, it was set on the line above.

And anyway, you can pass an empty variable to a function. No problem with that

Comment: I am talking about the line above that that is assigning

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter is a callback function, so its called after the assignment

Answer (score 0):

If a variable hasn't been assigned, it's treated as if it contains `null`. If you have warnings enabled, this will cause an "Undefined variable" warning to be logged, but the script will still run. Most likely, the `setContent()` function checks whether its argument is `null`, and if so it just returns the current contents without modifying it.

But this code seems very suspect to me. It's calling `setContent()` twice each time through the loop. The first line should only need to use `getContent()`, which shouldn't need an argument.